# Go exec.Command hangs on StrictHostKeyChecking=no

Tags: bash, go

I'm trying to ssh in to a group of servers that don't support a regular shell. The /crypto/ssh library doesn't work for these hence I'm using a direct ssh through `exec.Command`.

Now the problem is that this command just hangs if I pass `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` , i.e:
`exec.Command("ssh", "-o", "StrictHostKeyChecking=no", config.User + "@" + host)`

but works for a simple

`exec.Command("ssh", "-T", config.User + "@" + host)`

The full block of code is here (it basically just needs to pipe a command to an ssh connection like so

`echo hostname | ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@db1-ar6.name.local`:

```golang
p1 := exec.Command("echo", config.Command)
p2 := exec.Command("ssh", "-o", "StrictHostKeyChecking=no", config.User + "@" + host)
//p2 := exec.Command("ssh", "-T", config.User + "@" + host) //doesn't work

fmt.Println(p2) //checking output

var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
p2.Stdout = &stdout
p2.Stderr = &stderr

p2.Stdin, _ = p1.StdoutPipe()       // p1 pipe to p2 ssh


err1 := p2.Start()  // start ssh command but dont wait for it to finish
if err1 != nil {
  return errors.Wrap(err1, "starting ssh session failed")
        }

err2 := p1.Run()    // run pipe command and wait for it to finish
if err2 != nil {
  return errors.Wrap(err2, config.Command+" failed", )
         }


err3 := p2.Wait()   // ssh wait for pipe to close
if err3 != nil {
  return errors.Wrap(err3, "ssh wait failed")
         }
```

Output is, and the wait function fails:

```sh
&{/usr/bin/ssh [ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@db1-ar6.name.local] []  <nil> <nil> <nil> [] <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> false [] [] [] [] <nil> <nil>}
2019/05/24 10:28:41 ssh wait failed: exit status 255
```

Comment: Where is that output coming from? Assuming the caller of the code shown is printing the error returned, the quoted output doesn't match any of the returned errors.

Comment: sorry multiple iterations of the code changed the output. I've fixed it to show the latest, which comes from this line `return errors.Wrap(err3, "ssh wait failed")`, at other times for newer hosts it just hangs after printing the exec on first line.

Comment: You're recording the stdout/stderr from the command but don't seem to be doing anything with it. Have you tried logging that to see what the output is? It likely sheds some light on the issue.

Comment: It actually prints those to the screen later on in the code, I truncated that part since it never gets there and the wait hangs forever. I just tried adding some prints for those before the wait() and they are empty, so nothing is coming out.

Comment: It probably hangs because you never close the input. `ssh` is just sitting there waiting for something to happen until the connection times out and closes.

Comment: So the input from p1 that pipes to ssh should complete the execution, and interesting part is that it happens successfully that way if I omit `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` . But you're right, I have a feeling that is what the issue is and I can't quite figure out how to add a close, since the close call is only supported on StdinPipe

Comment: You're creating the pipe so you can assign it to a local var (which would be of type `io.ReadCloser`) and then close it when you need to. Since you know what you've assigned to `Stdin`, you could also do `p2.Stdin.(io.Closer).Close()`.

Comment: Nope, adding a close right before the wait didn't help. It doesnt seem to be capturing  any input.

Comment: Ah I captured the closing error, it says `closing failed: close |0: file already closed` ; so looks like the the connection either never establishes or closes immediately.